# C Error: Expected Unqualified-id Before '{' Token

Tags: c

What I'm inputting: `gcc -o plot plot_na22.C`.

What I'm getting: `plot_na22.C:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token`.

I have no clue what I'm doing. This is someone else's code and I don't know why it's not working. Any advice?

```
{
  // ROOT style junk
  gStyle->SetOptStat(0);
  gStyle->SetTitleFont(132, "XYZ");
  gStyle->SetLabelFont(132, "XYZ");

  // some constants for binning
  double qmin = 0.0;
  double qmax = 500.0;
  int qbins = 250;
  double fmin = 0.0;
  double fmax = 1.0;
  int fbins = 200;
  double rscale = 435.0;
  double rmin = 0.0;
  double rmax = pow(435.0 / rscale, 3);
  int rbins = 200;

  // 1D charge, fprompt, and scaled centroid histograms
  TH1D* hq = new TH1D("hq", "", qbins, qmin, qmax);
  hq->SetLineColor(4);
  hq->SetXTitle("Charge (PE)");
  TH1D* hf = new TH1D("hf", "", fbins, fmin, fmax);
  hf->SetLineColor(4);
  hf->SetXTitle("f_{p}");
  TH1D* hr = new TH1D("hr", "", rbins,
                      pow(rmin/rscale, 3), rmax);
  hr->SetLineColor(4);
  hr->SetXTitle("(r / r_{tpb})^{3}");

  // 1D reconstructed coordinate histograms
  TH1D* hx = new TH1D("hx", "", rbins, -rscale, rscale);
  hx->SetLineColor(4);
  hx->SetXTitle("Position (mm)");
  TH1D* hy = new TH1D("hy", "", rbins, -rscale, rscale);
  hy->SetLineColor(2);
  hy->SetXTitle("Position (mm)");
  TH1D* hz = new TH1D("hz", "", rbins, -rscale, rscale);
  hz->SetLineColor(3);
  hz->SetXTitle("Position (mmm)");

  // 2D histograms
  TH2D* hfq = new TH2D("hfq", "", qbins, qmin, qmax, fbins, fmin, fmax);
  hfq->SetMarkerColor(4);
  hfq->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hfq->SetMarkerSize(0.3);
  hfq->SetXTitle("Charge (PE)");
  hfq->SetYTitle("f_{p}");
  TH2D* hfr = new TH2D("hfr", "", rbins, rmin, rmax, fbins, fmin, fmax);
  hfr->SetMarkerColor(4);
  hfr->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hfr->SetMarkerSize(0.3);
  hfr->SetXTitle("(r / r_{tpb})^{3}");
  hfr->SetYTitle("f_{p}");
  TH2D* hqr = new TH2D("hqr", "", qbins, qmin, qmax, rbins, rmin, rmax);
  hqr->SetMarkerColor(4);
  hqr->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hqr->SetMarkerSize(0.3);
  hqr->SetXTitle("Charge (PE)");
  hqr->SetYTitle("(r / r_{tpb})^{3}");
  TH2D* hang = new TH2D("hang", "",
                        rbins/2, -TMath::Pi(), TMath::Pi(), rbins/2, -1.0,1.0);
  hang->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hang->SetMarkerSize(0.2);
  hang->SetMarkerColor(4);
  hang->SetXTitle("#phi");
  hang->SetYTitle("cos(#theta)");

  // create a tchain with the simulated data
  TChain* tree = new TChain("T", "T");
  tree->Add("/home/benjiang/fuck/realdata_*.root");
  RAT::DS::Root* ds = new RAT::DS::Root();
  tree->SetBranchAddress("ds", &ds);

  // count for the number of triggers
  int ntriggers = 0;

  // begin reading events
  for(int iev=0; iev<tree->GetEntries(); iev++){
    if(iev % 10000 == 0)
      printf("event %i\t of %i\t%i triggers\n", iev, tree->GetEntries(), ntriggers);
    tree->GetEvent(iev);
    // ignore this event if there wasn't an event trigger
    if(ds->GetEVCount() != 1)
      continue;
    RAT::DS::EV* ev = ds->GetEV(0);
    ntriggers ++;
    // ignore this event if a data quality cut failed for some reason
    if(!ev->GetPassAllCuts())
      continue;
    // get values from the data structure
    double q = ev->GetQPE();
    double f = ev->GetFprompt();
    TVector3 v = ev->GetCentroid()->GetPosition();
    double r = pow(v.Mag() / rscale, 3.0);
    // fill histograms
    hq->Fill(q);
    hr->Fill(r);
    hf->Fill(f);
    hx->Fill(v.X());
    hy->Fill(v.Y());
    hz->Fill(v.Z());
    hfq->Fill(q, f);
    hfr->Fill(r, f);
    hqr->Fill(q, r);
    hang->Fill(v.Phi(), TMath::Cos(v.Theta()));
  };

  // legend for 1D coordinate histograms
  TLegend* plegend = new TLegend(0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8);
  plegend->SetLineColor(0);
  plegend->SetFillColor(0);
  plegend->AddEntry(hx, "#font[132]{x}", "l");
  plegend->AddEntry(hy, "#font[132]{y}", "l");
  plegend->AddEntry(hz, "#font[132]{z}", "l");

  // canvases to draw the histograms
  TCanvas* c0 = new TCanvas("c0", "", 0, 0, 1400, 1200);
  c0->Divide(3, 2);
  c0->cd(1);
  hq->Draw();
  c0->cd(2);
  hf->Draw();
  c0->cd(3);
  hr->Draw();
  c0->cd(4);
  hfq->Draw("colz");
  c0->cd(5);
  hfr->Draw("colz");
  c0->cd(6);
  hqr->Draw("colz");
  c0->Update();
  TCanvas* c2 = new TCanvas("c2", "", 0, 0, 1400, 600);
  c2->Divide(2, 1);
  c2->cd(1);
  hx->Draw();
  hy->Draw("same");
  hz->Draw("same");
  plegend->Draw();
  c2->cd(2);
  hang->Draw("colz");
  c2->Update();

  // write the histograms and canvases to a root file
  TFile* outfile = new TFile("plot_na22.root", "recreate");
  outfile->cd();
  c0->Write();
  c2->Write();
  hq->Write();
  hf->Write();
  hr->Write();
  hfq->Write();
  hfr->Write();
  hqr->Write();
  hx->Write();
  hy->Write();
  hz->Write();
  hang->Write();
  outfile->Close();
}
```

Comment: @FiddlingBits Since the error says line 1, my guess is nothing.

Comment: You mean the first line of the file really is just a `{`?

Comment: *"This is someone else's code and I don't know why it's not working."* Because they wrote non-compilable (incomplete) code

Comment: If line 1 really starts with a `{` the file can only be used if `#include`ed at an appropriate place of another C source file. Do a `grep "include.*plot_na22.C" * -ir` on the source base in question to find this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a C file meant for ROOT. You can't compile it on its own with GCC. I'm unfamiliar with ROOT, but try this.

```
root plot_na22.C
```

Comment: As addition, one can (and I would say "should") write code that works in ROOT and can be compiled. Essentially by switching from an unnamed macro to a named macro (adding `void plot_na22()` before the `{` in the first line), and adding missing includes. You can then run with any of `root plot_na22.C` (interpret with ROOT), `root plot_na22.C+` (compile with ROOT) and `g++ $(root-config --cflags) $(root-config --libs) -o plot plot_na22.C`. Be sure to use a C++ compiler, not a C compiler, and provide the compiler and linker flags (from the `root-config` command).

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a C source file with `{` and compile it directly. It's just a syntax error. So fundamentally, you need to find out how/where this was meant to be used and use it in that way. [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk)'s suggestion seemed like a useful approach:

```
grep "include.*plot_na22.C" * -ir
```

Perhaps the original author was using this in an `#include` in a different file (which isn't a good idea, but does happen), but that's speculation. It certainly is highly suspicious that it happily starts using symbols (like `gStyle`) it hasn't defined or `extern`d.

Comment: Hopefully the original author wasn't doing that.  That would be dirty and nasty!

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Indeed it would.

Comment: As suggested by Joel, this file looks like it's meant for ROOT. Ideally one would write valid C++ which would then be accepted by any c++ compiler as well as ROOT. Yet ROOT is a bit more permissive and allows unnamed macros (at least until ROOT5, I don't know by heart how strict ROOT6 is).

This means the file is okay for what it's meant (although I would say it's not good practise to write root code that's not as well valid c++).